# Helicoil, epoxy or some other method to repair threads for swimming pool pump?

Tags: pool, bolts, chlorine

Jandy swimming pool pump's plastic backplate comes with what appears to be two metal threads to attach diffuser.

[image]

In my case threads rusted and diffuser came loose.

Instead of buying a new backplate I am considering to first give a shot and repair it.

What would be the recommended way to restore threads? In particular I am concerned about:

1. Constant submersion in chlorinated water.
2. Exposure to vibrations.
3. I am ok to permanently attach screws, but I can't upgrade to a bigger screw as the screw goes through diffuser wall that is very thin.
4. these are skinny 4-40 screws about 1.5 inchesl long that go in there.

Would helicoils, epoxy (if so would jb weld original work?) or some other solution be able to fare better in such case?

Comment: Does it have to be that exact orientation? If you can mount it a little sideways, I'd epoxy those closed and use [press-in threaded inserts](https://www.ezlok.com/e-z-press-inserts-for-plastic) in a slightly different location. You just heat them up with a torch and push them into the plastic (it helps to have an undersized guide hole drilled first).

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes the diffuser can be attached to the backplate only in one orientation.

Comment: You can probably remove the old inserts by heating them up with a soldering iron and pulling them out, then putting new ones in.

Comment: @RonBeyer I checked that website. My understanding is that for swimming pool applications 316 stainless steel is best followed by 304. Do you think brass or 303 handle chlorine well? Those are the only inserts I could find for plastic. Thanks for link thugh.

Comment: McMaster Carr has them in all types of metals/applications, check there too.